# To send multipart/form-data from ESB to APIM

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 ESB 6.4.0 and APIM 2.6.0

I am working on adding certificate in APIM server using rest API of APIM application.
In the request of adding a new certificate, the post request should be form-data.

So, to automate the process, I am using ESB server. I have written a proxy which will pick the certificate file and process it. Below is my proxy code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="ClientSslCertificateAdd-APIM" startOnLoad="true" transports="http https vfs" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <!--   <enrich>
            <source clone="true" type="body"/>
            <target property="originalBody" type="property" />
        </enrich>
        <property expression="get-property('originalBody')"
                name="payloadposttexttransformation"
                scope="default"
                type="STRING"/> -->
            <property expression="$body/*" name="payload" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="get-property('payload')" name="xml form certificate captured  ===" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <xslt description="" key="xmltotext"/>
            <property expression="$body/*" name="payloadpostmapping" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property name="filename" scope="default" type="STRING" value="filename_certifiate"/>
            <property name="alias" scope="default" type="STRING" value="alias_certifiate"/>
            <property name="endpoint" scope="default" type="STRING" value="endpoint_certifiate"/>
            <property name="uri.var.host" scope="default" type="STRING" value="http://apimserver.com/"/>
            <property name="uri.var.context" scope="default" type="STRING" value="certificates"/>
            <property expression="get-property('alias')" name="uri.var.resourcepath" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property name="Authorization" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="Bearer token"/>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="get" uri-template="{uri.var.host}/{uri.var.context}/{uri.var.resourcepath}"/>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
            <property expression="json-eval($.status)" name="currentstatusoftobeaddedalias" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <filter regex="Expired" source="get-property('currentstatusoftobeaddedalias')">
                <then>
                    <property expression="get-property('alias')" name="alias" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                    <property expression="get-property('endpoint')" name="endpoint" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                    <property name="Authorization" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="Bearer token"/>
                    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="multipart/form-data"/>
                    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                        <format>
                            <root xmlns="">
                                <certificate charset="UTF-8" contentType="text/plain" xmlns="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd/form-data">$3</certificate>
                                <alias xmlns="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd/form-data">$1</alias>
                                <endpoint xmlns="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd/form-data">$2</endpoint>
                            </root>
                        </format>
                        <args>
                            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:alias"/>
                            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:endpoint"/>
                            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:payloadpostmapping"/>
                        </args>
                    </payloadFactory>
                    <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
                    <!-- <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" value="multipart/form-data" type="STRING"/> -->
                    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="multipart/form-data"/>
                    <!-- <call>
                        <endpoint>
                            <http format="rest" method="post" uri-template="http://apimserver.com"/>
                        </endpoint>
                    </call> -->
                    <send>
            <endpoint>
            <http method="POST" format="rest"
                    uri-template="http://apimserver.com"/>
            </endpoint>
            </send>
                </then>
                <else>
                    <log>
                        <property name="alreadypresent" value="with entered alias name, certificate is active"/>
                    </log>
                </else>
            </filter>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
    <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">5</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file:///opt/new/esb/clientSSLcertificate_repo/</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">application/xml;charset=UTF-8</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">file:///opt/new/esb/clientSSLcertificate_repo/failed_clientSSLcertificate</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.xml</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file:///opt/new/esb/clientSSLcertificate_repo/updated_clientSSLcertificate</parameter>
</proxy>
```

I am first checking what is the status of the alias present in APIM server, if its expired then it should add the certificate.

also, I am picking the file from ESB local directory in xml form and converting the same in text/plain format in order to remove any residues and ensure that I am sending proper message to APIM server.

Once the request is hit to APIM server, I am getting below error in ESB server

```
DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "{"code":500,"message":"Internal server error","description":"The server encountered an internal error. Please contact administrator.","moreInfo":"","error":[]}[\r][\n]"
DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "0[\r][\n]"
DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "[\r][\n]"
DEBUG - headers http-outgoing-6 << HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
DEBUG - headers http-outgoing-6 << Server: nginx/1.16.1
DEBUG - headers http-outgoing-6 << Date: Wed, 06 Nov 2019 22:06:41 GMT
DEBUG - headers http-outgoing-6 << Content-Type: application/json
DEBUG - headers http-outgoing-6 << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
DEBUG - headers http-outgoing-6 << Connection: keep-alive
```

and error from APIM server is

```
ERROR - GlobalThrowableMapper An Unknown exception has been captured by global exception mapper.
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Couldn't find MIME boundary: --MIMEBoundary_4a754414be212aae0a86dd7fe9ddbf07662811acf9d618ec
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AttachmentInInterceptor.handleMessage(AttachmentInInterceptor.java:60)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContextImpl.createAttachments(MessageContextImpl.java:284)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContextImpl.get(MessageContextImpl.java:79)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.tl.ThreadLocalMessageContext.get(ThreadLocalMessageContext.java:42)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.multipart.AttachmentUtils.getMultipartBody(AttachmentUtils.java:143)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.multipart.AttachmentUtils.getAttachments(AttachmentUtils.java:155)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.MultipartProvider.readFrom(MultipartProvider.java:149)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBodyReader(JAXRSUtils.java:1355)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBody(JAXRSUtils.java:1307)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameter(JAXRSUtils.java:836)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameters(JAXRSUtils.java:795)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:214)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:78)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:191)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:220)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:65)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't find MIME boundary: --MIMEBoundary_4a754414be212aae0a86dd7fe9ddbf07662811acf9d618ec
        at org.apache.cxf.attachment.AttachmentDeserializer.initializeRootMessage(AttachmentDeserializer.java:140)
        at org.apache.cxf.attachment.AttachmentDeserializer.initializeAttachments(AttachmentDeserializer.java:109)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AttachmentInInterceptor.handleMessage(AttachmentInInterceptor.java:58)
        ... 54 more
```

From the error log it seems that APIM server is unable to get the attach files from ESB and which is why it is unable to process the request.

Does APIM 2.6.0 support multipart/form-data

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We had similar issue and we had to update messageFormatters and messageBuilders in axis2/axis2.xml file (in both ESB and APIM):

update messageFormatters:

```
<!-- <messageFormatter contentType="multipart/form-data" 
  class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.MultipartFormDataFormatter"/ -->
<messageFormatter contentType="multipart/form-data" 
  class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>
```

update messageBuilders

```
<!-- messageBuilder contentType="multipart/form-data"
  class="org.apache.axis2.builder.MultipartFormDataBuilder"/ -->
 <messageBuilder contentType="multipart/form-data"
  class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
```

These updates should change the transport to stream the payload without parsing and rebuilding it